# calculate how to cheapest get a certain amount of points in Excel

Tags: excel

If you have 5 packs with points (500, 1000, 2100, 5500, 11500) costing 2, 3, 5, 8 and $16.

How do you get Excel to calculate the cheapest way possible to get a certain amout of points?

You can calc how each pack (from high to low) can be subtracted from the amount, and hit it spot on, for example:

36500 = (3x 11500 + 2x 1000)

but 3x 11500 + 1x 2100 would be cheaper, and leave you with a little points surplus

Comment: See [Define and solve a problem by using Solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-Solver-9ed03c9f-7caf-4d99-bb6d-078f96d1652c).

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. The only thing you are missing is that there is a point where it is worth it to pay for "bonus points", because each value of pack has a better per-point rate than the pack below. For the $16 pack, the most you can get for $15 is 8100 points, so you should always calculate how many $16 packs can be subtracted from (the total + 8099), etc. This is a complete solution:

[image: Formulas]

[image: Result]